# Java AWT Event Dispatching

Tags: java, events, awt

I am new to java and AWT.

I am a bit confused about Event Dispatching. When an event happens on a component whether it will be delivered directly to component or it will be send to the top most container and container will traverse the hierarchy and send it to the component?

Comment: @pl.t.. : how about posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @siri your, my and their EDT only executed writen code that is compiled, nothing else, there isn't something magic, just execute some code, you are two options 1) you'll post code that demonstrated youd issue http://sscce.org/ , 2) let's it be, let's fade out :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When event occurs, it will dispatch based on hierarchy ordering of its containing components.

For ex: A contains B, B contains C, then if event in C occurs, it dispatch to B first, then to A, .etc.

Hth.